# 9時半, 9時 pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

I can only find 9時 in the online NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 which is only listed as くじ{HL}, and I assume for 9時半 it's くじはん{HLLL}: [1](https://youtu.be/LrglvEEieoY?t=371), [2](https://youtu.be/Hu8tBzAYn0U?t=247), [3](https://youtu.be/a7X3UWW01Nk?t=2060)

But I seem to also have heard くじはん{LHLL}. (or is it くじはん{LHHL}?): [4](https://youtu.be/YYD_BQfqmCI?t=780), [5](https://youtu.be/pw55c84GAWk?t=192)

Does 標準語 have both and if so what other factors are there that determine which one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position of the accent shifts like this.

- くじ{HL}
- はん{HL}
- くらい{HLL} (or ぐらい{HLL})
- はんくらい{HHHLL} (or はんぐらい{HHHLL})
- くじはん{LHHL} [#3, #4, #5]
- くじはんくらい{LHHHHLL} (or くじはんぐらい{LHHHHLL}) [#1]

Only #2 is a bit irregular where くじ{HL} and はんくらい{HHHLL} are put together with the accent of each portion retained. He may have wanted to emphasize はん.

#3 may sound a bit like くじはん{HHHL}, but it’s still recognized as くじはん{LHHL}.

---

[Edit]

Theoretically, はんくらい is はんくらい{LHHLL}, but pitch doesn't rise on ん in standard Japanese. So it becomes はんくらい{HHHLL} (if we have to use this notation).